# C++ "delayed" template argument

Tags: c++, templates

Is there direct way to do the following:

```
template < class >
struct f {};

template < class F >
void function() {
    F<int>();  //for example
    // ? F template <int>();
}

function < f >();
```

I have workaround by using extra class around template struct.
I am wondering if it's possible to do so directly.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the intent behind that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sharp instantiate template inside function (above is just example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper syntax for template template-parameters is as follows

```
template < class > struct f {}; 

template < template <class> class F > 
void function() { 
    F<int>();  //for example 
} 

...     
function < f >()
```

Comment: I know I have seen this syntax before.  now I actually know how to use it.
spasibo

Comment: Wow! Never seen the template<class> without naming the class. Where can I read more on that?

Comment: @sharptooth: There's not much to read here. Just like with ordinary function parameters, if you are not using the template parameter you don't have to name it.